# Me da un error de compilacion y nose por que ¿como lo podria solucionar?

Tags: c++

```
#Include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Class Ejemplo.                                 
{
Private:                                              
   Int  Variable_1;                             
   const int variable_2;                   
Public:
   Ejemplo(int a, int b);
   Ejemplo();
};

Ejemplo::Ejemplo(int a, int b)
:variable_1(a), variable_2(b)
{
    Cout << variable_1 << endl << variable_2 << endl;
}

Ejemplo::Ejemplo()
{
     Cout << "Mensaje" << endl;
)

Int main()
{
     const Ejemplo(10, 11);
     Ejemplo();

    rturn 0;
}
```

Comment: Deberias de ver [Como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder ayudarte, debes de poner que error te da, y lo que quieres realizar con tu programa para que podamos ayudarte. Edita tu pregunta para entender mejor tu problema, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores tipográficos:
0. El punto "." final después de Class Ejemplo, sobra
00. es **include** en vez de Include
1. es **class** en vez de Class
2. es **private** en vez de Private
3. es **public** en vez de Public
4. es **int** en vez de Int
5. es **cout** en vez de Cout
6. Has definido Variable_1 y luego en la llamada al constructor Ejemplo(int a, int b) utilizas variable_1
7. El constructor Ejemplo::Ejemplo(), acabas la función con un ")" cuando deberías hacerlo con una llave "}"
8. El const en la variable_2 te dará problemas si no inicializas la variable en todos los constructores